# materialize range slider delayed

Tags: html, css, slider, materialize

```css
.range-field {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=range],
input[type=range]+.thumb {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range] {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]+.thumb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  border: none;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  margin-left: 7px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type=range]+.thumb .value {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #26a69a;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

input[type=range]+.thumb.active {
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
}

input[type=range]+.thumb.active .value {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 3px;
  background: #c2c0c2;
  border: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  margin: -5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #ccc;
}

input[type=range] {
  /* fix for FF unable to apply focus style bug  */
  border: 1px solid white;
  /*required for proper track sizing in FF*/
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  height: 3px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: none;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: none;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #26a69a;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

input[type=range]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-moz-range-track {
  background: #ccc;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  height: 3px;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 6px 0;
  /*remove default tick marks*/
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #777;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ddd;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  border: none;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #26a69a;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #888;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<p class="range-field">
  <i class="material-icons prefix"></i>
  <input type="range" id="range1" min="0" max="10" value="0" />
</p>
```

The problem is when dragging the thumb along the track pop up value is not directly above the thumb as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SKoR.png)

Dragging the thumb along the track is fine and the value changes accordingly, however the value displayed is not centered.

The CSS code provided is taken from materialize css, I'm not sure if it's needed or if it will help.

If any other information is required please let me know!

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you take a look here? Maybe it will help http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize-v1.0/advanced-ui-range-slider.html

Comment: Thanks! This looks very promising :)